# Entity Framework 4.1 and BLOBs

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I'm trying to work out what the best way to work with BLOBs and entity framework.

I am working with EF 4.1, and using POCO's/DbContext

So here's and example table:

```
MyTable
Key int
SomeFields ...
ABlob  (ok, it's actually a Text, but whatever)
```

Now, sometimes when I select from MyTable, I want to include the BLOB field, but a lot of the time, I don't.

Also, sometimes, when I update MyTable, I want to update the BLOB.  but a lot of the time, I don't.

I could use anonymous types for the select operation, but I cannot seem to find a way to make this work at all for updates (I can't have 2 different classes in the same context mapped to the same table, if I try to use inheritance, I get a runtime error because EF is expecting a discriminator column).

Surely using EF doesn't mean that I always have to query all of my BLOBs.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be done using Table Splitting. [EF 4.1](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/04/24/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-4-table-splitting.aspx) and [EF 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/12/05/table-splitting-mapping-multiple-entity-types-to-the-same-table.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can try by calling a stored procedure or execute the SQL statement from your code :

```
var result= context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT yourfield FROM yourtable").ToList();
```

[Here some documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/using-dbcontext-in-ef-4-1-part-10-raw-sql-queries)

Comment: Thank you Girgio.  I will keep this in mind, but I am really trying to find a way to do this that still works with LINQ, and doesn't require stored procs.

Comment: Hi, you can use that snippet by specifying an entity as the return type and execute the SQL statement from your code(without calling sp). The fields of the select should match the properties of the destination class. You will than have a list you can query with linq.